# ASP Net Core - Storing data temporarily across views

Tags: asp.net-core

I have an ASP.Net Core 3.1 web app trying to pass data across a wizard form using `TempData`. The app goes through a series of 3 steps. However on saving the data to the database, only the last form's data is saved meaning my data is not held.

I have the function below to store the data which apparently isn't:

```
    private TripLogData GetData()
    {
        if (TempData["TripLogData"] != null)
        {

            TempData["TripLogData"] = new TripLogData();
        }
        return (TripLogData)TempData["TripLogData"];
    }
```

Below is the continuation of the controller code:

```
        private void RemoveData()
    {
        TempData.Remove("TripLogData");
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Add(Step1 data, string nextBtn, string BtnCancel)
    {
        if (BtnCancel != null)
        {
            TempData.Clear();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        if (nextBtn != null)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                TripLogData obj = GetData();
                obj.Destination = data.Destination;
                obj.Accomodation = data.Accomodation;
                obj.StartDate = data.StartDate;
                obj.EndDate = data.EndDate;
                ViewBag.Accomodation = data.Accomodation;
                TempData["Destination"] = data.Destination;

                return View("Page2");
            }
        }
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Page2(Step2 data, string BtnCancel, string nextBtn)
    {
        TripLogData obj = GetData();
        if (BtnCancel != null)
        {
            TempData.Clear();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        if (nextBtn != null)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                obj.AccomodationPhone = data.AccomodationPhone;
                obj.AccomodationEmail = data.AccomodationEmail;

                return View("Page3");
            }
        }
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Page3(Step3 data, string BtnCancel, string nextBtn)
    {
        TripLogData obj = GetData();
        if (BtnCancel != null)
        {
            TempData.Clear();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        if (nextBtn != null)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                obj.ThingToDo1 = data.ThingToDo1;
                obj.ThingToDo2 = data.ThingToDo2;
                obj.ThingToDo3 = data.ThingToDo3;
                TempData["TripLogData"] = db.TripLogData.Add(obj);
                db.SaveChanges();
                RemoveData();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
        }
        return View();
    }
}
```

TripLogData Model is as below:

```
    public int? TripId { get; set; }

    public string Destination { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [Display(Name = "Start Date")]
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [Display(Name = "End Date")]
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

    public string Accomodation { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Phone Number")]
    public string AccomodationPhone { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Email Address")]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    public string AccomodationEmail { get; set; }

    public string ThingToDo1 { get; set; }
    public string ThingToDo2 { get; set; }
    public string ThingToDo3 { get; set; }
```

Any advise on the same would be appreciated.

Comment: Use Session storage or insert data on submit of each step to the database.

Comment: @RyanWilson Submitting each step leads to multiple record entries. It won't maintain one record line

Comment: The TempData stores data until it's read in another request. And if using the `TempData.Clear();` method, it will clear all items in the TempData. You could set break point in these methods and check the TempData value. Perhaps the TempData is cleared, and if you want share value between action method, try to use session state. Reference: [Session and state management in ASP.NET Core](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-5.0#tempdata). If the problem continues, can you share the related model and create a simple sample to reproduce the problem?

Comment: @ZhiLv On setting breakpoints, I realized the data is not stored after I move to another view

Comment: @Nickson Then you should be doing an Update if the record exists and not an Insert.